# Interpreting GD info through PHP

Tags: php, gd

I was checking my GD library and when I ran this code :-

```
<?php

$a=gd_info();
foreach ($a as $key=>$value){
    echo $key | $value . '<br>';
}
?>
```

It gave me the following output :

```
gunvmwwio~.0.34 compatible)
w~gw~ype Supportw{umtree|y~o}gw>|s~b Supportw}fr~ead Supportw}frreate Support{|gw>Supportq~grupportw~or>Support|r>Supporty~orupport~ks?mapped Japanese Font Support
```

I know how to get the correct output. But I just want to know the exact meaning of this output.

Answer (score 2):

First off, that gibberish text you created isn't exactly correct. To properly show the correct values wrap the quotes correctly:

```
$a = gd_info();
foreach ($a as $key=>$value){
    echo "$key | $value <br/>";
    // wrap them all including the pipe
}
```

So that in return you'll get something like this:

```
// the actual correct output
GD Version |    2.0.36
FreeType Support |  1
FreeType Linkage |  with freetype
T1Lib Support | 
GIF Read Support |  1
GIF Create Support |    1
JPEG Support |  1
PNG Support |   1
WBMP Support |  1
XPM Support |   
XBM Support |   
JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support |
```

Actually this info is basically same as looking into `phpinfo()` info on your GD

[image]

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yDNbQ2)